# Need to find a number whose column name matches with a row vector

Tags: r

I have a data set (`df`) below that needs a variable which for example grabs the date on a column (with names as years below) and grabs the variable `start_year` and finds the value of it for that year and type (`newstart`). I have many more years and types in my dataset than below so something that works across any number of years is needed.

Here's what I have for data (a simplification):

| st | type_num | start_year | end_year | 2000 | 2001 | 2002 | 2003 | 2004 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| il | 1 | 2000 | 2004 | 10 | 220 | 9 | 10 | 100 |
| il | 2 | 2001 | 2004 | 220 | 100 | 220 | 100 | 100 |
| il | 3 | 2000 | 2004 | 400 | 400 | 10 | 220 | 220 |
| ak | 1 | 2001 | 2003 | 10 | 220 | 9 | 10 | 100 |
| ak | 2 | 2001 | 2004 | 220 | 100 | 220 | 100 | 100 |
| ak | 3 | 2000 | 2003 | 400 | 400 | 10 | 220 | 220 |
| wa | 1 | 2001 | 2003 | 10 | 220 | 9 | 10 | 100 |
| wa | 2 | 2001 | 2004 | 220 | 100 | 220 | 100 | 100 |
| wa | 3 | 2000 | 2003 | 400 | 400 | 10 | 220 | 220 |
| wa | 4 | 2002 | 2003 | 500 | 600 | 700 | 800 | 900 |

Where's what I need:

| st | type_num | start_year | end_year | 2000 | 2001 | 2002 | 2003 | 2004 | newstart | newend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| il | 1 | 2000 | 2004 | 10 | 220 | 9 | 10 | 100 | 10 | 100 |
| il | 2 | 2001 | 2004 | 220 | 100 | 220 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| il | 3 | 2000 | 2004 | 400 | 400 | 10 | 220 | 220 | 400 | 220 |
| ak | 1 | 2001 | 2003 | 10 | 220 | 9 | 10 | 100 | 10 | 10 |
| ak | 2 | 2001 | 2004 | 220 | 100 | 220 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| ak | 3 | 2000 | 2003 | 400 | 400 | 10 | 220 | 220 | 400 | 220 |
| wa | 1 | 2001 | 2003 | 10 | 220 | 9 | 10 | 100 | 220 | 10 |
| wa | 2 | 2001 | 2004 | 220 | 100 | 220 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| wa | 3 | 2000 | 2003 | 400 | 400 | 10 | 220 | 220 | 400 | 220 |
| wa | 4 | 2002 | 2003 | 500 | 600 | 700 | 800 | 900 | 700 | 800 |

I was trying to get those variables using a couple indexes, tried this

`which(colnames(df)==df$end_year[1])`

Which seems to grab the column number of the matching date column, but wasn't able to figure out how to use it in an `apply()` to get it to do what this variable needs to do.

I also tried to make a less specific data set that got some suggestions to use `rowwise()` and `get()` but that didn't seem to work exactly, perhaps due to the less specific data. I tried to make something almost exactly what I intend to use for my real output.

Comment: Hi, if you can it would be helpful to add your data using `dput(df)` or `dput(head(df))`. Read through this post for some hints about how to format a question as a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/12400385

Comment: R typically averts using numeric values as column names (though not impossible). Is this actually what your data look like?

Comment: I think it's how the data looks like, yes. It may still code them as names but this is what's in there. Also, I have data that I cannot put a full head the actual data due to privacy reasons, so I have recreated it as best as I can.

Comment: The way you have it now is not easily reproducible. Please edit your question to make it reproducible. Look into manually making it a data frame (`data.frame(st = c(“Il”,…))`) or `dput`. If you read the link provided above it goes through all of this. The easier you make it for folks here the faster and better help you’ll get. (Just genuinely trying to help, not being snarky)

Answer (score 0):

I used `pivot_longer()` on the original data set I was merging in, solved the issue.